# Python launch subprocess script, monitor results, and restart if there is no activity

Tags: python, while-loop, subprocess

I'm working on a function that launches an external script using the subprocess module, the script runs sends/receives data files from a server, and does this for ~ 10,000 different files.  The service occasionally gets hung up and can be continued if it gets relaunched.  The external script saves the files (.xml) into a folder, so the function is complete when the number of input files equals the number of *.xml files in the output folder.  This is what I have thus far, the second while loop seems to work - which is monitoring if there has been no files updated in the folder for 30 minutes, it should terminate the process.  However, in the first while loop, after the process is terminated, it does not restart.  Any help would be great!

```
from __future__ import division
import subprocess, datetime, time, os, glob

def runIPRscan(path, input, outputdir, email, num_complete):
    num_files = len(glob.glob1(outputdir,"*.xml"))
    while (num_files < num_complete):
        #launch process
        p = subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', path, '$@', '-i', input, '-m', email, '-o', outputdir], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        time.sleep(180) #give the script a few minutes to get running
        while p.poll is None:
            #wait 30s and check again
            time.sleep(30)
            num_files = len(glob.glob1(outputdir,"*.xml"))
            if num_files == num_complete:
                break
            #monitor the output folder for recent changes in last 30 minutes
            now = datetime.datetime.now()
            ago = now - datetime.timedelta(minutes=30)  #if nothing happens in 30 minutes, relaunch service 
            file_list = []
            for path in glob.glob(outputdir + "/*.xml"):
                (mode, ino, dev, nlink, uid, gid, size, atime, mtime, ctime) = os.stat(path)
                if datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(mtime) > ago:
                    file_list.append(path)
            if not (file_list):
                print("No activity in last 30 minutes, restarting service")
                try:
                    p.terminate()
                except OSError:
                    pass
                time.sleep(10) #give it a few seconds to make sure process is closed before exiting
                break
        num_files = len(glob.glob1(outputdir,"*.xml"))
```

Comment: i think you mean `java` not `javascript`

Comment: yes, sorry.  an external script written in java.  Which is I guess irrelevant to my question.

Comment: your problem is going to be with this expression `(num_files < num_complete)`, so I would print out the values of `num_files` and `num_complete` at the bottom of the loop, and work backwards from there.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out.  So it was actually a problem with the external script that was giving an error message to stderr but I couldn't see it because it was in the subprocess PIPE.  So the above while loops are correct (I think), but I ended up replacing the external script with a python version and things seem to be working now.  Thanks.